# alfresco folder tree opencmis

Tags: java, playframework, alfresco, opencmis

i have to create folders in alfresco with the following path:

COMPANY_HOME/TEST/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/DOCUMENT

currently i can create a folder like this:

```
Map<String, Object> newFolderProps = new HashMap<>();
        newFolderProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
        newFolderProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "folderName");
        Folder folder = baseFolder.createFolder(newFolderProps);
```

Can i create the folder tree with a string path? like this:

```
Map<String, Object> newFolderProps = new HashMap<>();
        newFolderProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
        newFolderProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "TEST/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/DOCUMENT");
        Folder folder = baseFolder.createFolder(newFolderProps);
```

Or i need to create the folders separately?. 
some one have done this??
im using opencmis, java 7 and play framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to pass the folder path in the PropertyIds.Name value. What you can do is make a recursive method while creates folder and pass the parameter value as the created folder id, so if this method is called 5 times, your hierarchy will be created.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Session.createPath()](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/javadoc/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/api/Session.html#createPath-org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.ObjectId-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-). It takes the path and creates all folders in the path that don't exist.